# How to rank column in r data frame based on another column

Tags: r, dataframe, rank

Supposed I have an R data frame that looks like this:

```
#sample data frame
df <- data.frame(
customer_id = c(568468,568468,568468,568468,568468,568468),
customer = c('paramount','paramount','paramount','paramount','paramount','paramount'),
start_date = as.Date(c('2016-03-15','2016-03-15','2016-03-15','2016-03-15','2016-03-15','2016-03-15')),
occured_on = as.POSIXct(c('2017-08-08 20:05:00','2017-08-08 20:30:00','2017-08-11 21:13:00','2017-08-11 21:30:00','2017-08-31 05:16:00','2017-08-31 05:30:00')),
old_plan = c('a',NA,'b',NA,'b',NA),
old_price = c(NA,29,NA,99,NA,82.5),
old_recurrence = c('monthly',NA,'monthly',NA,'annually',NA),
new_plan = c('b',NA,'b',NA,'c',NA),
new_price = c(NA,99,NA,82.5,NA,349),
new_recurrence = c('monthly',NA,'annually',NA,'monthly',NA)
);
```

**Task:**

rank the old_plan, old_price, old_recurrence as the first in each group based on the min occured_on time... 
and the new_plan, new_price, new_recurrence, based on the max occured_on time...
such that my resulting data frame would have the first old plan, price and recurrence, and the last new plan price and recurrence. 
NAs should be removed/not taken into account. The resulting dataframe should look like this:

```
customer_id  customer start_date old_plan old_price old_recurrence new_plan new_price new_recurrence
568468 paramount 2016-03-15        a        29        monthly        c       349        monthly
```

or if you want to see in your code

```
result_df <- data.frame(
customer_id = 568468,
customer = 'paramount',
start_date = "2016-03-15",
old_plan = 'a',
old_price = 29,
old_recurrence = 'monthly',
new_plan = 'c',
new_price = 349,
new_recurrence = 'monthly'
)
```

I feel I'm close using functions like these...

```
df$old_plan_rank <- rank(df$old_plan, na.last = "keep", ties.method = "min")
df$new_recurrence_rank <- rank(df$new_recurrence, na.last = "keep", ties.method = "max")
```

except it's ranking based on order or alphabetically/numerically, not on the order it actually occurred based on the occurred_on column. I don't know how to specify a column for which to rank on.

Help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution using `dplyr`.

```
library(dplyr)

df2 <- df %>%
  arrange(customer_id, start_date, occured_on) %>%
  group_by(customer_id, customer, start_date) %>%
  summarise(old_plan = first(old_plan[!is.na(old_plan)]),
            old_price = first(old_price[!is.na(old_price)]),
            old_recurrence = first(old_recurrence[!is.na(old_recurrence)]),
            new_plan = last(new_plan[!is.na(new_plan)]),
            new_price = last(new_price[!is.na(new_price)]),
            new_recurrence = last(new_recurrence[!is.na(new_recurrence)])) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  as.data.frame()
df2
#   customer_id  customer start_date old_plan old_price old_recurrence new_plan new_price new_recurrence
# 1      568468 paramount 2016-03-15        a        29        monthly        c       349        monthly
```

**Explanation**

`arrange(customer_id, start_date, occured_on)` is to sort the columns. It sorts the columns by `customer_id`, and then, `start_date`, finally `occured_on`.

`group_by(customer_id, customer, start_date)` means to perform the following operation in each group based on `customer_id`, `customer`, and `start_date`.

`summarise` generates single summary output for each variable.

For each variable, take `old_plan` as an example, I used `old_plan[!is.na(old_plan)` to extract the non-NA values of that column. After that, `first` and `last` can extract the first or the last element of those values, which corresponding to the minimum and maximum in terms of time.

`ungroup()` is to remove the grouping. `as.data.frame()` is optional, which converts the `tibble` object to strictly `data.frame` object.

Comment: AMAZING! Thank you so much! I don't think I could've figured it out going down the path I was on!